# Trying to compare each element location, and if the location are the same return false, otherwise return true

Tags: python, probability, physics

I have tried to write here a code that takes a random permutation `from random_list` and compares each element's location. I do get a False and True result but not sure that my code goes through the list and compares every single element. Any suggestion will be helpful.

```
  def not_correct_order(n):
    randomList = random_List(n)
    counter = 0
    while (counter <n):
        if(randomList[counter] == counter):
                return False
                counter = counter+1
        return True
```

tried a.any() and a.all() and a i thought using np.isclose().

Comment: This returns False if the first element is 0, and True if the first element is 0.  It doesn't look at any other elements.  Did you want `return not all(i == randomList[i] for i in range(len(randomList)))`?  Or `return not all(i==j for i,j in enumerate(randomList))`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: @TimRoberts, Thanks for your help. But what I am looking for is my code to go through each element and compare the value of the element with its position. for example: `randomList = [3,1,0,2]` I want to go through the list and get false bcz 3 is not in the correct location and True for 1 being in its position. Is that a possibility ?

Comment: You said (or you implied) that you wanted a single value that says whether the list is in order or not.  Do you actually want a judgement for each element?  All you have to do is change the "not all" in my comment to "list", to convert the generator to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Roberts, he helped me to figure out my answer. by using `a.any()` I could compare my list to its position and if any element was not in the correct position it gives back a false.

```
def not_correct_order(n):
  randomList = random_List(n)

  return any(i==j for i,j in enumerate(randomList))
```